# почему qjsondocument приходит пустой на сервер через qdatastream?

Tags: c++, qt

client

```
QDataStream out(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QJsonDocument doc;
out << quint16(0) << doc;
out.device()->seek(0);
out  << quint16(data.size() - sizeof(quint16));
logInWindow->socket->write(data);
```

server

```
socket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
QDataStream in(socket);
QJsonDocument doc;
in  >> doc;
```

Когда клиент передает только jsondocument, то всё приходит, но если передавать ещё и его размер, то на сервере он пустой.
как я могу передать jsondocument и его размер?

Comment: А кто Вам рассказал про такую интересную перегрузку операторов `>>` и `<<` ? Вы их реализовали?